# Can the method redirectToRoute() have arguments like render()?

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, routes

I need to access an entity in twig from symfony2.
Inside the controler, I can do something as:

```
return $this->render('frontendBundle::carrodecompras.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity
));
```

And then in twig I can access the entity properties with `entity.name` and such.

I need to accomplish the same thing but with the function `redirectToRoute()`

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('frontend_carrodecompras', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
));
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

I'm getting the following error:

Variable "entity" does not exist in frontendBundle::carrodecompras.html.twig at line 32

EDIT: I'm using Symfony 2.7

The variable $entity exists (it's actually called $cortina in the app I was using $entity for simplification), just before the redirectToRoute function I did this to test it

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($cortina);
echo "</pre>";

return $this->redirectToRoute('frontend_carrodecompras', array(
                'cortina' => $cortina,
                ));
```

And the result is this:

```
object(dexter\backendBundle\Entity\cortina)#373 (16) {
  ["id":"dexter\backendBundle\Entity\cortina":private]=>
  int(3)
  ...
```

This is the Twig code:

```
<tr>
    {% set imagentela = "img/telas/" ~ cortina.codInterno ~ ".jpg" %}
    <td><img src="{{ asset(imagentela | lower ) }}" alt="" width="25" height="25">
    </td>
    <td>{{ cortina.nombre }}</td>
    <td>{{ "$" ~ cortina.precio|number_format('0',',','.') }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You should confirm and make sure that `$entity` actually does exist.

Comment: the entity is being persisted to the database before the redirectToRoute method is called, so the $entity exists!

Comment: I doubt that `$entity` actually exists where you're calling `redirectToRoute`. Can you provide additional context? Perhaps the function that is calling redirectToRoute if it's not too large? Or at least showing the code path from where `$entity` is defined to where it's being used?

Comment: I edited the question to show the variable exists. The problem is that the function redirectToRoute is not passing the variable to twig.

Comment: How you want to sent object via url? Serialize it first. Why just not pass entity id to route and fetch it in another controller?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misread. The error you're asking about is coming from your twig template. So you need to look at either the template or the render call to make sure the proper variable is being passed in and used. But you probably also don't want to redirectToRoute to an entity object; you probably want to ['entity' => $entity->getId()].

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you call `redirectToRoute($route, array $parameters)` from a controller, `$parameters` is used to generate the url tokens, not variables to render in view, this is done by the controller assigned to the route you are redirecting to.

example :

```
class FirstController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route('/some_path')
     */
    public function someAction()
    {
        // ... some logic
        $entity = 'some_value';

        return $this->redirectToRoute('some_other_route', array('entity' => $entity)); // cast $entity to string
    }
}

class SecondController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route('/some_other_path/{entity}', name="some_other_route")
     */
    public function otherAction($entity)
    {
        // some other logic
        // in this case $entity equals 'some_value'

        $real_entity = $this->get('some_service')->get($entity);

        return $this->render('view', array('twig_entity' => $real_entity));
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution solved the problem. I wasn't passing the $entity variable in the otherAction (the one I was originally redirecting to).

Answer (score 1):

`$this->redirectToRoute('something', array('id' => 1)` is a convenience wrapper to `$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('something', array('id' => 1)))`. It builds a URL with your params and is expecting the value of the params to be a string or a number.

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-new-shortcut-methods-for-controllers

You need to either pass the id of the entity to then fetch the data in the new action or break it down into individual pieces of data before it hits the redirectToRoute() call.

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    public function myAction(){
        $cortina = new Cortina();
        $cortina->something = "Some text";

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($cortina);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('frontend_carrodecompras', array(
            'id' => $cortina->getId()
        );
    }
}
```