# symfony how to retrieve parameters in redirectToRoute

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony.
In one action, I fill in some form, use getData to get the filled in data and want to pass to another action to do query in database.

```
$input=$form['input']->getData();
return $this->redirectToRoute('anotherpage', array('input'=>$input ));
```

In action of anotherpage, how to retrieve the information of input?
It shows no default value for it which means I'm not passing it correctly.
Hope to get some help. THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you properly, you may try this:

Just define the default value in action where you try to recieve input

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function anotherAction($input = 'defaultValue')
    {
        // do somth with $input
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your response. but I think my problem is that I'm not passing arguments using redirectToRoute, which means that if I set the default value like you do, the input will always be the default value... I see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775342/can-the-method-redirecttoroute-have-arguments-like-render   I think Heah's answer makes sense, but do you know what does $real_entity = $this->get('some_service')->get($entity); means? thanks

Comment: Don't forget to specify in your routing that you're passing this argument. If you're using annotations, it will look like this : @Route("another/{input}", name="another")

Comment: so what if I pass multiple arguments in redirectToRoute? How to specify in routing? thanks!