# How can I output the Cart item number?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i was wondering of how can i show how many items i got in the cart? I did a path in the twig but im not sure how to show it.
[image]

this is my controller i have the route and in the twig i call the path with the name (count_panier).

```
/**
    * @Route("/count/{qtt}", name="count_panier")
    */
    public function testAction($qtt,Request $req)
    {
       
       $qtt = $this->afficherCount($req);

       
        
      return $this->redirectToRoute('mag',['count'=>$qtt]);
                                                        
    }

//----------------------------------------------

    public function afficherCount(Request $req){

      $sess = $req->getSession();

      $panier = $sess->get('panier',[]);

      $qtt = 0;

      foreach($panier as $item)
      {
        $qtt += $item->quantiteCommandee;
      }

    
    
      return $qtt;


    }
```

And this is my twig, this is the part of the top navbar

```
    <div class="menu">
        <a class="active" href="{{path('mag')}}">Catalogue</a>
        <a href="contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#creeCompte">Crée un compte</a>
        <a href="#connexion">Connexion</a>
        <a href="panier">Panier
        <img width="30" alt="img" src="{{asset('images/cart.png')}}"/></a>

        <span id='panierCompteur'>
        
         <a href="{{ path('count_panier', {'qtt': 0}) }}"></a> 

         items</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: use render controller, https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your Controller you are passing just one parametere `count => '$qtt`

So in the Twig file, if you want get it, do this:

```
{{ count }}
```

So if you want to get a link that shows how many items you have, do like this:

```
 <span id='panierCompteur'>
        
         <a href="{{ path('count_panier'}}"> {{count}} </a> 

         items</span>
```

(you are not usign the $qtt variable so don't pass it)

```
/**
    * @Route("/count", name="count_panier")
    */
    public function testAction(Request $req)
    {
       
       $qtt = $this->afficherCount($req);

       
      return $this->redirectToRoute('mag',['count'=>$qtt]);                                         
    }

//----------------------------------------------

    private function afficherCount(Request $req){

      $sess = $req->getSession();

      $panier = $sess->get('panier',[]);

      $qtt = 0;

      foreach($panier as $item)
      {
        $qtt += $item->quantiteCommandee;
      }

   
      return $qtt;
    }
```

Of course the first time you render this main page you need to run the function `afficherCount()` in the index Controller (or whatever is your main controller) and return to the main page the `count => '$qtt` with all your others arguments.

You are redirecting to another route, so you need to "handle" the redirection if you want to get those parameters:

```
   /**
    * @Route("/your-route/{count?}", name="mag", requirements={"count"="\d+"})
    */
    public function yourFunction(Request $req, $count)
    {
      // true if is the first time you render this page or if you don't pass the value
      if($count === null){
         $count = afficherCount($req);
      }

      return $this->Render('yourTwigFile.html.twig',['count'=>$count]);                                         
    }
```

`{count?}` : the `?` if for optional parameters so the first time you render this page is not necessary to pass the value in the URL

`requirements={"count"="\d+"}` : the value can only be an integer

(PS. this function is probably your index)

[for more information / examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775342/can-the-method-redirecttoroute-have-arguments-like-render)

Comment: when i do it that way i get a error message that says "count" does not exist

Comment: @Ray at the end it wokrs after the changes that I posted?